# vector бросает исключение при многопоточной обработке

Tags: c++, многопоточность, boost, vector

Есть функция `outputMutex`

```
void outputMutex() {
    while(bOutput){
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(mOutput);
            if (massOutput.size() > 0) {
                string qwe = massOutput.front();
                cout << qwe;
                massOutput.erase(massOutput.begin());
            }
        }
    }
    massOutput.clear();
}
```

Она работает в потоке

```
boost::thread outputThread(outputMutex);
```

`outputMutex` должен выводить сообщения только когда есть очередь

```
massOutput.push_back(123\n");
```

Всего отправлено через `push_back` 5к сообщений.

Сейчас всё работает нормально, однако, если прогу вызвать второй раз, сразу после завершения первого, то вылетает ошибка "...вызвал срабатывание точки останова", а если второй вызов произошел через 3-5 сек, то всё хорошо.

Причем всегда жалуется на строчку

```
string qwe = massOutput.front();
```

Такое чувство, что в `massOutput` остаётся мусор, который не сразу удаляется, не смотря на вызов `massOutput.clear()` в начале и в конце работы программы. Что можно придумать, что бы такого не было?

UPD:

Примерно такой код выходит

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost\filesystem\fstream.hpp>
#include <boost\thread\thread.hpp>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <future>
#include <io.h>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

mutex mOutput;
bool bOutput = true;

vector<string> massOutput;

void outputMutex();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    boost::thread outputThread(outputMutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        massOutput.push_back(" " + to_string(i) + " \n");
    }
    //bOutput = false;
    system("pause");
    bOutput = false;
}

void outputMutex() {
    while (bOutput) {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(mOutput);
            if (massOutput.size() > 0) {
                cout << massOutput.front();
                massOutput.erase(massOutput.begin());
            }
        }
    }
    massOutput.clear();
}
```

UPD2:

Итоговые изменения:

```
lock_guard<mutex> locker(mOutput);
massOutput.push_back(filePath.filename().string() + " :\n");
queuecheck.notify_one();



void outputMutex() {
    while(bOutput){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mOutput);
        if (massOutput.size() > 0) {
            cout << massOutput.front();
            massOutput.erase(massOutput.begin());
            queuecheck.wait(locker);
        }
    }
    massOutput.clear();
}
```

Comment: Что значит `прогу вызвать второй раз, сразу после завершения первого`? Вы про исполняемый файл? Если так, то видимо какие-то ресурсы неправильно освобождаете типа сокетов забинженых. Короче говоря, приведите более точное описание ошибки и попробуйте создать [mcve], чтобы все желающие могли повторить Ваш эксперимент.

Comment: `massOutput.front();` приводит к UB, если вектор ещё пустой, видимо это и происходит. Т.е. синхронизация между потоками неправильно настроена.

Comment: @alexolut добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я и предполагал, проблема в отсутствии синхронизации доступа к элементам вектора из разных потоков исполнения.

Вызов [`std::vector::front`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/front/) на пустом векторе приводит к UB:

> Calling this function on an empty container causes undefined behavior.

Хотя, здесь видимо проблема в том, что в момент вызова `front` или `erase` происходит `push_back`. В любом случае - нарушении синхронизации доступа к вектору.

Самый тупой способ это добавить защиту мютексами везде, где идёт обращение к вектору, ну и использовать `std::atomic<bool>` вместо обычного `bool`. Немного пришлось изменить условие в цикле, и добавить ожидание окончания выполнения потока в `main` с помощью `outputThread.join();`, т.к. не отсоединенные потоки при вызове деструктора `thread` приводят к UB, если они ещё не завершились.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

mutex mOutput;
std::atomic<bool> bOutput(true);

vector<string> massOutput;

void outputMutex();

int main() {

    boost::thread outputThread(outputMutex);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(mOutput);
        massOutput.push_back("123\n");
    }

    bOutput = false;
    outputThread.join();
}

void outputMutex() {
    while (bOutput || massOutput.size() > 0) 
    {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(mOutput);
            while (massOutput.size() > 0) {
                cout << massOutput.front();
                massOutput.erase(massOutput.begin());
            }
        }
    }

    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mOutput);
    massOutput.clear();
}
```

[Проверка выполнения](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LqXZUPKzV8X4GOLZ).

Более правильный способ - использовать условные переменные [`std::condition_variable`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) вместо активного ожидания. По ссылке есть и пример подходящий.

Comment: Тот неловкий момент, когда заметил ответ только спустя 30 минут :D Спасибо, буду думать над  `std::condition_variable`

Comment: @Виталий я его удалял потому что. Т.к. сначала несколько ошибся с выводами :) Может и сейчас не всё так гладко, как хотелось бы. Надо более углублённо в код смотреть, а не в полглаза как я сейчас. Тема многопоточной обработки данных довольно обширная. Есть где запутаться.

Comment: Если у Вас есть желание - можно будет посмотреть в лс или скайпе (vitalik89151).

Comment: @Виталий спасибо, но нет :) Лучше задавайте вопросы здесь на сайте. Желающие ответить на хороший вопрос найдутся. Главное, старайтесь выделить суть и свести проблему к [mcve].

Comment: Вместо `join()` можно делать `detach()`...

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну я написал, что это для не отсоединённых потоков. Зависит от задачи в общем, если надо дождаться завершения, то `join`, если уже не важно, то `detach`.

Comment: @alexolut добавил версию с `condition_variable` т.к. я их до этого не использовал, хочу знать, я их правильно применил? Ошибки не выбивает.

Comment: @Виталий не стоит всё изменения (особенно существенные) пихать в один вопрос. Лучше - задайте новый (а в нём можете дать ссылку на этот), если видите какую-то новую проблему. Здесь принято на одну проблему задавать один вопрос. Так проще и быстрее находить ответы.